# Soundcloud API: Are there any restrictions for apps in development mode?

Tags: soundcloud

Apart from being in the App Gallery, what difference does it make for an app to be in development mode?

I couldn't find any information on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no functional differences. The majority of registered apps are not in the App Gallery and therefore are still in development mode.